# Get the file name, on insert or update event blob (bytea) field in attribute form QGIS

Tags: qgis, postgresql

We have PostgreSQL table blob_storage, withc 3 fields:
blob_id int4,
blob_body bytea,
blob_name text

Form attribute settings in QGIS:
[image]

How to get file name, on insert or update event blob (bytea) field in attribute form QGIS and put this file name in field “blob_name”?
[image]

Answer (score 0):

You can use function that is called when the dialog is opened. To write this function, you need to click on the button with the Python icon on your screenshot. More details here: [QGIS Documentation](https://docs.qgis.org/3.28/en/docs/user_manual/working_with_vector/vector_properties.html#enhance-your-form-with-custom-functions)

Sample code:

```
 from qgis.PyQt.QtWidgets import QWidget, QMenu, QAction, QFileDialog
 import psycopg2, os

 def form_open(dialog, layer, feature):
     global dialog_global, feature_global, layer_global
     dialog_global = dialog
     layer_global = layer
     feature_global = feature
     
     menus = [child.findChildren(QMenu) for child in dialog.findChildren(QWidget, "blob_body")][0]
     for menu in menus:
           actions_list = menu.actions()
           action_names = [action.text() for action in actions_list]

           if "Embed File…" in action_names:
               menu.clear()
               embed_action = menu.addAction("Embed File")
               embed_action.triggered[bool].connect(embed_action_triggered)

               clear_action = menu.addAction("Clear Contents")
               clear_action.triggered[bool].connect(clear_action_triggered)

               menu.addSeparator()
               download_action = menu.addAction("Save Contents to File")
               download_action.triggered[bool].connect(download_action_triggered)
          elif action_names:
               clear_action = actions_list[action_names.index("Clear Contents")]

          if clear_action:
              if feature.isValid() and feature['blob_body']:
                  clear_action.setEnabled(True)
              else:
                  clear_action.setEnabled(False)

  def embed_action_triggered(checked):
      filter = "Documents (*.png;*.jpg;*.mp3;*.mp4;*.pdf;*.docx;*.doc;*.txt)"
      file_path, _ = QFileDialog.getOpenFileName(dialog_global, "Select File", "./", filter)
      if file_path:
          file_name = os.path.basename(file_path)
          
          # need to set variables 'dbname', 'user', 'host', 'pw', 'port'
          conn_param = "dbname='{0}' user='{1}' host='{2}' password='{3}' port={4}" \
            .format(dbname, user, host, pw, port)

          try:
              conn = psycopg2.connect(conn_param)
              conn.set_client_encoding('UNICODE')
        
              cur = conn.cursor()
              with open(file_path, 'rb') as file:
                  file_data = file.read()
              BLOB = psycopg2.Binary(file_data)
              
              cur.execute('''UPDATE blob_storage SET blob_body = %s, 
                   blob_name = %s WHERE blob_id = %s''', 
                   (BLOB, file_name, feature_global['blob_id']))
    except Exception as e:
        print(repr(e))
    finally:
        if conn is not None:
            conn.commit()
            conn.close()
        dialog_global.refreshFeature()

def clear_action_triggered(checked):
     ...

def download_action_triggered(checked):
     ...
```